# How to handle one line answers vs comments

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality, comments

When someone posts a comment such as "I haven't tried software XYZ, but it looks like it might meet you requirements", we keep it (unless it's spam).  Why?  Because it is helpful and is better than nothing (or could even be a better solution than some of the actual answers posted).

But when someone posts an answer like "Try software XYZ, it will work well.", we typically delete the answer, because it's not a high quality answer (it doesn't contain sufficient information).

The result, in the second case, is that we lose a recommendation that would have otherwise been kept if it was originally posted as a comment.

What do you recommend we handle the dichotomy between these two cases?

Comment: Second category lacks the info whether it meets the requirements at all (if I ask for a boat and get told a car "works well", it doesn't help me at all) – so in that case I'd delete it. If it seems useful, it can be converted into a comment (by us mods at least).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks.  On the mod tool that converts answers to comments, it recommends not converting low quality answers to comments.  But maybe we are a unique enough community that the recommendation is not a fit for us.  What do you think?

Comment: Well, delete "bullshit" but convert "useful comments". If we shouldn't convert VLQ answers, what do you think this tool is for? To convert "high quality answers" into comments? Makes no sense :) IMHO they mean exactly what we were saying here: convert posts that are no answers but useful hints in the context of the question. Same as you'd convert an answer by the OP which should have been an edit to the Q. That could also be considered a VLQ answer (but probably a good edit), right?

Comment: @Izzy I agree with you.

Comment: Shall I sum it up in an answer then?

Comment: @Izzy.  Sure.  We're going to need someone to blame. :)

Comment: Aw. I knew it. OK, so go on, punish me with upvotes…

Answer (score 3):

The second category ("Try software XYZ, it will work well.") lacks the info whether it meets the requirements at all (if I ask for a boat and get told a car "works well", it doesn't help me at all) – so in that case I'd delete it. If it seems useful, it can be converted into a comment (by us mods at least).

You point out it's said never to convert/migrate low quality posts. That's right, to a degree: Delete "bullshit" but convert "useful comments". If we shouldn't convert VLQ answers, what do you think this tool is for? To convert "high quality answers" into comments? Makes no sense :)

IMHO they mean exactly what we were saying here: convert posts that are no answers but useful hints in the context of the question. Same as you'd convert an answer by the OP which should have been an edit to the Q. That could also be considered a VLQ answer (but probably a good edit), right?